# Pasiva refleja vs el impersonal con verbos modales?

Tags: gramática, concordancia-gramatical, oraciones-impersonales, oraciones-pasivas-reflejas

Me dijeron otro día que nunca se permite una frase así

> No se puede hacer**lo**

porque la frase es una pasiva refleja, que exige un sujeto, no un OD, por lo tanto no se permite el pronombre 'lo'.  En vez de usar 'lo', sí se podría usar un sujeto como 'eso'

> No se puede hacer **eso**

Lo acepto, pero en mi mente siempre había pensado que el verbo modal 'se puede' aquí indicaba un cierta 'impersonalidad', es decir, que el verbo modal 'se puede' era equivalente a 'uno puede', y que *no* estábamos ante la pasiva refleja, casi como si el verbo modal se hubiera separado de lo demás de la frase (pensaba en la traducción española de 'Yes we can!' a 'Sí se puede', por ejemplo, lo que me parecía como una frase *impersonal*)

¿Lo había conceptualizado completamente incorrectamente (lo cual es lo más probable), o ¿existen circunstancias en las que una frase como 'se puede hacerlo' sí se pueda usar?

Comment: [Se me dijeron el otro día]. No se puede hacerlo de esta manera. No veo porque no iría.

Comment: Más bien tiene que ser 'me dijeron'....

Comment: Puede ser it/one/they/you, depende de si quien relata se desentiende ('se') del asunto o toma esa responsabilidad ('lo'). Eso es lo que se me dijo(=That's what I was told)/Eso es lo que me dijeron(=they told me) || No se puede hacer así = One/It could do it that way || No se puede hacer->lo<- X || ¿Cómo se puede averiguar eso? = how can you find that out? || Qué se puede hacer? = what can you do?

Comment: Que no lo podía hacer = It couldn't be done that way, perfectamente acá puede no usar 'I', es decir que él no podía hacerlo, como digo, depende de como relata el hecho quien lo escribió, si quiere cargarle la responsabilidad a otros, a nadie o a el mismo.

Answer (score 1):

"No se puede hacer eso" puede ser, en efecto, impersonal (sin sujeto, en cuyo caso "eso" es objeto) o pasiva con "se" (con sujeto pasivo "eso"):

- No es posible hacer eso (impersonal)
- Eso no puede ser hecho (pasiva)

El problema es que "se" atrae al pronombre átono:

- No se **lo** hace de ese modo: se **lo** hace de esta manera.

La atracción del pronombre también funciona con perífrasis verbales. Si bien decimos:

- No **lo** puede hacer / No puede hacer**lo**.

"se" atrae a "lo":

- No se **lo** puede hacer.

Lo mismo ocurre con perífrasis de gerundio:

- **Lo** va haciendo / Va haciéndo**lo**.

pero:

- Se **lo** va haciendo.